# Google DataFlow fails writing on bucket

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm not able to run sample wordcount dataflow. An error appear:

```
(venv) dh4@GLOW:$ python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
                 --project "$PROJECT"   --runner DataflowRunner \
                 --staging_location $BUCKET/staging \
                 --temp_location $BUCKET/tmp \
                 --output $BUCKET/results/output
```

> IOError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://prova_df/staging/beamapp-dh4-1014444431-510588.1505555051.55555: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.

But I have not permission problems in this bucket:

```
(venv) dh4@GLOW:$ gsutil cp  paraules.txt gs://prova_df
Copying file://paraules.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
- [1 files][   24.0 B/   24.0 B]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/24.0 B.
```

Some extra info:

- I can create folders on bucket from web interface
- I've checked for twice enabled APIs, all seems right.
- I have `owner project role` on `service account`.
- I `rm ~/.gsutil/credstore` to ensure no cache credentials.
- I'm using json `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`
- [Complete stack error at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/3dqVJbpV) to keep post clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing the question, I closed my laptop and I went for a walk. I take a picture of an octopus.

[image]

Then I come back to office, start laptop again and when I try again without change any single line of config neither code it works without problems:

[image]

Then, it looks that take for a while to enable all resources. Just be patient and go hunting octopus (with your camera)